# Where is the recommended place to install applications that are not from apt?

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure

The SDK for Dart comes as a [zip file for Linux](https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/archive/). I've only previously installed software using `apt-get`. Is there a convention for where I should put the `dart-sdk` folder? And should I add `dart-sdk\bin` to my path, or symlink it into a folder that's already in the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [arch package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/dart/files/), it seems Dart gets installed into `/opt/dart-sdk`. This also seems to match with what [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) says:

> `/opt` is reserved for the installation of add-on application software packages.
>
> The use of /opt for add-on software is a well-established practice in the UNIX community. The System V Application Binary Interface [AT&T 1990], based on the System V Interface Definition (Third Edition), provides for an /opt structure very similar to the one defined here.

The Arch package also seems to be put stuff in `/usr/bin` (I suspect symlinks to the things in `/opt/dart-sdk/bin`).

Comment: It is bad practise to put stuff in `/usr/bin`. `/usr/local` is another place that I think is reserved. I don't know the difference between `/usr/local` and `/opt`. On my system, `/opt` has stuff arranged by package, and `/usr/local` I use for stuff that likes to spread it self out in to bin, libs etc.

Comment: The Arch package puts stuff under `/usr` because that's where stuff installed by the package manager is supposed to go. Conversely, when you aren't using the package manager, don't put stuff under `/usr`, except under `/usr/local` which is for stuff *not* coming from a package.